# EXCEL - How can I use conditional formatting to color code if this week's value has increased by more than 5% from the previous week's value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I'm tracking the increase or decrease of the percentage total of risks that are classified as being caused by something specific (the Business, IT, legal, Organisation, Security, etc) from report to report and I'd like to use conditional formatting to show when a value has increase by more than 5% than the previous week's value.  Currently, per report I have columns for each of the risk 'causes' and I put the percentages per week. ie.  Business - 36% / Security - 40% If in my next report, there is an increase of Security-related risks to 46%, I'd like the cell to automatically become red. Can somebody please help me figure out how to implement this in my excel sheet?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: share sample data of what you currently have, and what you want it to look like

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a conditional formatting rule based on a formula. Select your column data that you want to affect, then create your conditional format rule such as this:

```
=c2-b2>=0.05
```

And change your format fill to red.

[image]

Final results:

[image]